# I have a main method and NetBeans IDE does not recognize it

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I have a new problem with my Netbeans IDE, I want to show you, today I was going to work on my project and the Netbeans doesn't show me errors in my code Editor, let me show you:

[image]

In this image the IDE does not show me the errors in my code and then:

[image]

My IDE does not recognize my "main" class

And the last one:

[image]

This are my errors in my NetBeans IDE, also I tried to delete the Cache from de Cache folder and it still doing nothing, I hope that you can help me with this project

Comment: Code needs to be included in the question (as text blocks) so that changes in external sites don't make it disappear.

Comment: Looks strange. Normally a class within a main method is recognized and the icon should change as well. Can you paste/show the full source of that class. Just to be sure: Do you have saved the file? It seems that there are non saved changes.

Comment: [1] Show the entire 'SistemaPuntoVenta' class as embedded text, and not as a linked screen shot, which only shows it from line 16 anyway. [2] That approach is a very strong convention here. By posting a linked image you reduce the audience for your question, and it makes it impossible for others to attempt to reproduce your problem. [3] Do other projects with a `main()` method compile and run OK? [4] You are asking two distinct questions (errors not being reported vs. main() method not found). Remove one of them or your question may be closed. The rule is just one question per post here.